# How to store obtain id based on name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am work on a maintenance project which consists of imports.

My file:

### app/importers/contacts_importer.rb:

```
require 'csv'

class ContactsImporter < BaseImporter

  def import
    ..............
    sales_exec = fetch_value(row, "Sales Exec", :string) 
    email = fetch_value(row, "Email", :string) 
    ...................
        sales_exec_id = nil
        if sales_exec.present?
          sr = @file_import.account.users.where(initials: sales_exec).first
          sales_exec_id = sr.try(:id) if sr.present?
        end
        sales_exec_id = sales_exec_id 

        if company.present? 
          customer = Company.new
          customer.name = company
          customer.phone = phone
          customer.email = email
          customer.sales_exec = sales_exec_id
        end
  end

end
```

My requirement is I am able to store name, phone and email but could not get sales_exec_id.
Here sales_exec are users which are having role_name (Sales Executive, Product Manager etc) in roles table.
The relation is user has_many roles through user_roles(consists of role_id and user_id).
Is there any way to write query to match sales_exec (which displays Venkat, John etc) in my code with sales_exec_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since not having your whole system environment and the csv file, I would suggest two approaches.

```
    if sales_exec.present?
      sr = @file_import.account.users.where(initials: sales_exec).first
      sales_exec_id = sr.try(:id) if sr.present?
    end
```

1. add `puts sr` add see the output in terminal
2. see the query SQL in terminal and you could debug it in your DB GUI